# Best way to protect integrity of ajax request

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, security, drupal

I am building a Drupal website with a lot of user-specific information that will be posted using jQuery/ajax. The information it self is not very sensitive, it is just important to verify that the form-data has not been tampered with tools like Firebug, as well as ensuring the information is really requested from the specified user. In other words, I am trying to figure out the best way to protect the integrity and authenticity of the data when posting with ajax.

Ideally I would like to use some well known message authentication system, like the HMAC algorithm. But since this incorporates a symmetric key, I don't see how I can encrypt the POST data without exposing the secret key in my javascript file (which obviously is visible to anyone).

Please correct me if I have got the wrong idea about how this should work.

For example, info I need to send

```
field1=x&field2=y&uid=10
```

...then calculate the hash of the data together with a secret key. Is this possible to do without exposing the hash function in my javascript code?

```
CHECKSUM: hash(postdata, "secret_key")
```

... and finally append checksum to original postdata.

```
field1=x&field2=y&uid=1&c=CHECKSUM
```

### Alternative

An alternative I though of was using the session ID of the logged in user. This however would not check the integrity of the message...

When generating form with PHP, I can generate a hidden input with following

```
CHECKSUM: hash(session id for the current user, "secretkey")
```

What I then would post using ajax is

```
field1=x&field2=y&uid=10&c=CHECKSUM
```

With this it would be fairly secure to authenticate the appropriate user (again pseudo-code)

```
ssid = SELECT ssid FROM sessions WHERE uid = $_POST[uid]
if(ssid && hash(ssid, "secretkey") == $_POST[c]) {
     //User OK
} else {
     //Invalid user
}
```

Comment: "it is just important to verify that the form-data has not been tampered with tools like Firebug". If someone can tamper with the `POST` data, they can recalculate a checksum with ease since it has to be in your Javascript code base somewhere. I don't think the time you would spend on this would be worth it.

Comment: OK, so how would you solve the problem?

Comment: What is wrong with people using Firebug?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot do what you're trying to do. Basically, you're trying to verify that one component (your form) on an untrusted and uncontrolled client is not tampered with by another component on that same client. You don't control the client. You can come up with all sorts of methods to make it *harder* for someone to do this on their client, but in the end you must expose how you're doing those integrity checks to the client. Whatever you do in your form scripts can be read and understood by the person on that client (it has to run on the client, so whomever is interacting with the client can reverse engineer anything you're doing to recover the techniques used and any keys/etc that you have to enable your scheme).

Basic rule of web application security is that you cannot control what's happening on the client, so you cannot trust client-side verification/security schemes like this.

In the end, it's unlikely that the protection offered by such a scheme would be worth the time and investment to implement it. Someone who is determined to break it will be able to.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it makes complete sense... Integrity obviously can't be verified. But more generally, what is the approach for verifying authenticity of the user would you say?

Comment: Have the user login and establish a session, so you can verify that each request comes from a logged in user. You should also implement your site using SSL/TLS, so that session tokens/cookies cannot be stolen and used by other parties to impersonate users.

Comment: OK, then I am already doing it right then :) (Except for the SSL part.. probably not going to be worth the time & money. After all, I'm not doing bank transactions or anything even near)

Comment: @hakanito: You can get a SSL cert for [free](http://www.startssl.com/); there's really no excuse to skip the half-hour of configuration.

Comment: I'll second what @josh3736 says and tell you that SSL is worth the (small amount of) effort needed to get it going. (Also, if you're happy with my answer, please click the checkmark to accept :)).

Comment: Thanks guys =) I will definitely look into it

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned by others, you can’t control the client side. And that means you can’t control and thus can’t trust what the client sends and anything could be tampered.

But now think about this: The less parameters you expose to the client, the less they could tamper. So try to keep as much parameters in control (i. e. on the server side) as possible. That’s what sessions are used for.

So you could store the parameters that are not to be changed in the session instead of sending them to the client where they are out of your control. All you need is to associate the form instance with the server side form parameters. You can do this with a random identifier that you use as key in the session data array:

```
$data = array('uid'=>10);
$id = generateRandomIdentifier();
$_SESSION['formdata'][$id] = $data;
```

Then when you process the form request you just take the form data identifier to look up the form data in `$_SESSION['formdata']` to get the data for further processing.

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely no way to prevent someone from making "fake" requests. You just have to think this way:

> If my web browser can make this request, anyone (manually or not) can make it.

If you put some kind of encryption on the user-side, then it'll be easy for anyone to get how you made your encryption, and then do the same manually. For example, when you are talking about hashes:

```
hash(session id for the current user, "secretkey")
```

Your `secretkey` is not secret, because it's inside of a javascript file.

The only thing you can do is to throw a spanner in the "hacker"'s works. For example, you can get this secretkey from an AJAX request. This secret key would be unique and deleted on every successful request. In a more general way, you'll have to move the logic of your application as close to the server-side.

Comment: Actually, that alternative was ment to do all calculations on the server. As it says, PHP generates the form with the pre calculated hash value. But thanks for the input

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep `uid` stored server-side.  This is usually accomplished by storing it in a [session](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php) variable.

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['uid']
```

Because your server stores the session data, it is impossible for a client to tinker with their session's data.  The best a malicious user could hope for would be to hijack someone else's active session key, which is not a practical attack on a properly secured system.

[See also this detailed write-up about why we use sessions.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8993070/201952)

Answer (score -1):

May be this page will help: http://www.jcryption.org

Check my answer on following mention issue

[Securing and/or encrypting (hiding) POST variables in a jQuery ajax request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5327054/securing-and-or-encrypting-hiding-post-variables-in-a-jquery-ajax-request/19666267#19666267)